# Powershell cannot be loaded on Windows10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am running powershell to fetch running application. It works fine in Windows 7 but I got an error when I try to run it on Windows 10. Something about Authorization. This is the error

> D:\z.test\getprocess.ps1 : File D:\z.test\getprocess.ps1 cannot be
>   loaded. The file  D:\z.test\getprocess.ps1 is not digitally signed.
>   You cannot run this script on the current system. For  more
>   information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see
>   about_Execution_Policies at 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
>   + D:\z.test\getprocess.ps1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

What seems to be the problem here? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Run PowerShell as Administrator and type:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

read about Powershell Execution Policy [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847748.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir. I've tried executing the code you've given, it would still give me the same results

Comment: please close all powershell windows. Open a new PS console and type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` - what do you see?

Answer (score 3):

Please see this technet page:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx

Powershell has a policy option on what scripts to run. The policy can be set to:

- Restricted - No scripts can be run. Windows PowerShell can be used
  only in interactive mode.
- AllSigned - Only scripts signed by a trusted publisher can be run.
- RemoteSigned - Downloaded scripts must
  be signed by a trusted publisher before they can be run.
- Unrestricted - No restrictions; all Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

If you are happy to accept the security risks then run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

However I recommend signing your scripts. If you have a code signing certificate then you can sign your script using the following:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My\2C096472E989BA373512C307829E8E557A12BD93
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath C:\path_to_script.ps1
```

Replace C:\path_to_script.ps1 with your path to your script you wish to sign and replace cert:\CurrentUser\My\2C096472E989BA373512C307829E8E557A12BD93 with a path to your code signing certificate in the Windows certificate store.